# Windows 7 does not offer rebol view as file opener

Tags: windows, explorer, rebol

I have Rebol Core 278 and Rebol View 278 in a folder c:\rebol under Windows 7.

I copied an .r file via email from my work computer to this one at home.
No matter what I do Win 7 will not allow me to change the program to open this Rebol script from my basic text editor to c:\rebol\rebol-278 view. I have core in the folder as noted....it only offers Rebol Core as an option ...but this is a GUI script. I tried putting Rebol View under c:\program files also as well as present location........still won't allow me to use the 'change' function under 'properties for the script to use Rebol View, which is of course, also true  when using "open with" after right clicking the script. At work this .r file always opens with Rebol View as expected (also on Win 7). I'm astounded that nothing can get the same response on Win 7 at home ??? I "can" execute the script by opening Rebol View and "doing" the file but am used to just clicking the file name to achieve that result for scripts.

Comment: This is likely more a Windows question than a Rebol question.  Probably has to do with security privileges or registry settings or something along those lines.  A screenshot would help identify it.  See [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/153465/always-use-this-program-to-open-these-files-is-grayed-out-why) on SuperUser (which is where this kind of question is usually asked vs. StackOverflow--this is more for code.)

Comment: did you install Rebol/View? What happens if you start Rebol-view +i ?

Comment: Open a console window as administrator and run a windows explorer window there, exloprer exe. Do those changes on that window.

Answer (score 2):

Steps 1-4 are required if you are not already signed on as Administrator. Otherwise just open the Control panel from the start menu.

1. Navigate to through the Start Menu to
   'Start/All Programs/Accessories' and Right Click on 'Command Prompt'
2. 'Run as administrator'
3. Allow the program to make changes to the computer
4. In the command prompt window type 'control' and press enter.
5. In the 'Adjust your computer's settings' select the word 'Programs'
6. In the 'Programs and Features' select 'Make a file type always open in a specific program'.
7. In the 'Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program' scroll down and in the 'Name' column, select '.r'.
8. To the right and top of the box that displays the file types click on the 'Change program' button.
9. In the 'Open with ...' pop up window either choose the 'Rebol/View System' icon or if not shown then click on the 'Browse' button on the lower right.
10. Find and select the 'Rebol.exe' file. (On my system it was in 'Program Files (x86)/rebol/view').
11. Click 'Open'.

That should do it.